# UIPageViewController: position the page indicator

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I've successfully implemented UIPageViewController but would like to reposition the page indicator/pagecontrol from the default position at the bottom of a page to a higher position.

Here's an example of moving the page indicator higher on the page: http://s3.amazonaws.com/uxarchive/flows/174/1/2/medium/3/b43cf746d80940ff8780faf450eca41622f4d17c.png?1385333582

Does anyone know how to do this? The only documentation I can find is for changing the available frame size to accommodate the "child" viewcontroller.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this is not possible. I've recently done this using a separate `UIPageControl` element and update it manually on page changes. And for the PageViewController you need to set `spineLocation` to none to hide the default indicator.

Comment: there is no setSpine... on a UIPageViewController... you should add some code to explain it better...

Comment: You can set it to `none` using interface builder See: http://dbecker.net/scrups/n/2p32fn135q.png